# Should I return true to clear .map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function warning?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I was getting this warning:

> Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return

I cleared it by adding a `return true` outside of the `if/else if` statement, i.e.:

```
arr.map(foo => {
  if (foo.attr === 'someKey') {
    return baz
  } else if (foo.attr === 'someOtherKey') {
    return bar
  }
  return true //adding this return value clears the warning
})
```

Would this create any problems, or is this an okay way to clear that warning? I'm learning React so I just want to make sure I'm not developing any costly bad habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because you still had not specified what to return when `foo.atr` is neither `someKey` or `someOtherKey`. Returning `true` specifies what to return in this case. But it could be any valid value

Comment: I switched to a ```switch``` statement with a default, accepting this answer because it was more relevant to my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `return true` for your piece of code. You can write your callback implementation inn a different way so that your linter doesn't give you the false warning

```
arr.map(foo => {
  if (foo) {
    return baz;
  } 
  return bar;
})
```

In the above code, `return bar` will only execute if the `if condition` was false otherwise your code will return early and not reach `return bar`

UPDATE:

If you have a if-else-if rule, you can return undefined from the map function and filter out undefined values  using `filter(Boolean)`. It is needed you map needs to return something and if none of your conditions map, there is on return value specified

```
arr.map(foo => {
  if (foo.attr === 'someKey') {
    return baz
  } else if (foo.attr === 'someOtherKey') {
    return bar
  }
  return; 
}).filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: Apologies I just realized I wasn't asking the correct question. I updated the question code example, in my case I have an if/else if statement where I'm comparing keys...